# es6 babelify changes variable name, variable can't be found in inspector

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6, babeljs, source-maps

I am using es6 modules in my application, and I am encountering a problem when debugging in my chrome inspector. When I do something like the following in my code:

```
import 'widget' from './widget'

class SomeClass {
  componentDidMount(){
    debugger; // widget is not defined here according to chrome console!
    widget.doSomething();
  }
}
```

Looking at the compiled source file which the browser is reading, I see that the babelify transform that was applied to the original js files has renamed the 'widget' variable into something like '_widget_Js'. However, I have compiled the JS along with source maps, so the chrome inspector shows the original JS files, but doesn't recognize it when I refer to the original 'widget' variable (it *does* see the '_widget_Js' variable, but I certainly don't want to have to look up the compiled translated variable every time I debug!) .

Any suggestions on how I can get chrome to recognize the original import name? If it helps, I can provide more information on my setup (gulp + browserify + babelify). Thank you!

Comment: Don't have a solution that'll make it work straight up, but you can find the altered name in the Scope panel of the inspector. Also, if you have a reference to it inside your code (`let this.widget = widget`) then you'll be able to find it (usually) as `_this.widget`.

Comment: You've got a syntax error in the first line. It should be `import widget from '…'`.

Answer (score 2):

There's really nothing you can do. If Chrome implements support for the mappings in source map `names`, that will help somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

As @JMM notes source mapping variable names doesn't work currently. Babel has to change the variable names of the imports in order to support [exported bindings](http://www.2ality.com/2015/07/es6-module-exports.html) from ES2015 modules.

I created a Babel 6 plugin called [babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs-simple](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs-simple) that will import modules without changing the symbol names, at the cost of breaking the "bindings" behavior of ES6 modules. It's up to you to decide if this tradeoff is worth it. Since this concept doesn't even exist in CommonJS it was an easy one for me to make.

It's a drop-in replacement for `babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs`:

```
> npm install babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs-simple --save-dev
```

.babelrc:

```
{
    plugins: [
        "transform-es2015-arrow-functions",
        "transform-es2015-template-literals",
```

... more plugins

```
        ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs-simple", {
            noMangle: true
        }],
        "sourceMaps": true
    ]
}
```

If you are using presets, it's a little trickier, since there's currently no clear way to override plugins from presets, there are instructions on [the repo](https://github.com/jamietre/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs-simple).

You can switch on or off the behavior anytime with the `noMangle` option. The plugin tracks the version and indeed much of the source code of the native babel commonjs transform.